# How to set CSS using JSON data retrieved with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I am working on an dynamic HTML document that has to change its styling based on Google Sheets entries. So far it loads the JSON data just fine. I have been looking for a way to style the CSS so I can change it on the fly. Is there anyone that can point me in the right direction?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Google Sheets</title>
  <style>
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ourRequest.open('GET', 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1d3z-eJz2X_rFhq3a1kQ6TRlxJqHvstLQ/1/public/full?alt=json')
    ourRequest.onload = function () {
      var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
      var adTekst = ourData.feed.entry[6].gs$cell.inputValue;
      var achtergrondKleur = ourData.feed.entry[7].gs$cell.inputValue;
      var tekstKleur = ourData.feed.entry[8].gs$cell.inputValue;

      console.log(adTekst);
      console.log(achtergrondKleur);
      console.log(tekstKleur);

      document.getElementById('testoutput').innerHTML = adTekst + " " + achtergrondKleur + " " + tekstKleur;
    };

    ourRequest.send();

  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="testoutput"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: document.getElementById('testoutput').style.color = tekstKleur; document.getElementById('testoutput').style.backgroundColor = achtergrondKleur;

Comment: While diving into the DOM and toggling classes based on JSON data would work just fine, depending on the scale of your project you may want to look into some sort of reactive library such as React or Vue, or at the very least abstract some of it by extracting code into functions to handle specific aspects of your project.

Comment: @Gerard Thank you. This worked perfectly. Right now i'm trying the same with an image using style.backgroundImage = "url('IMG')" where 'IMG' is a variable i have set for my URL. It will not work, however when I replace the variable for the URL it represents, it does. Can you tell me what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by toggling classes using javascript.

```
document.getElementById('testoutput').classList.toggle('myClass');
```

Other way is to change individual CSS properties

```
 document.getElementById('testoutput').style.backgroundColor = 'RED';
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you also give specific css to all columns with using html tags. See snippet below

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Google Sheets</title>

<style>

</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET', 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1dLbBxSuyGxbG3z-eJz2X_rFhq3a1kQ6TRlxJqHvstLQ/1/public/full?alt=json')
ourRequest.onload = function() {
var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
var adTekst = ourData.feed.entry[6].gs$cell.inputValue;
var achtergrondKleur = ourData.feed.entry[7].gs$cell.inputValue;
var tekstKleur = ourData.feed.entry[8].gs$cell.inputValue;

console.log(adTekst);
console.log(achtergrondKleur);
console.log(tekstKleur);

document.getElementById('testoutput').innerHTML ='<span>'+adTekst+'</span>'+ " " + '<span>'+achtergrondKleur+'</span>' + " " + tekstKleur;
};

ourRequest.send();

</script>
</head>

<style>
div#testoutput {    color: red;}
div#testoutput span {    color: blue;}
div#testoutput span:first-child {color: aqua;}
</style>
<body>

<div id="testoutput"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

You can give color or design as per your requirement.